# Show full number on New Relic count column

Tags: newrelic, nrql

When I search for `SELECT count(*) FROM requests WHERE foo = 'bar' FACET dateOf(eventtime) SINCE 3 days ago` in New Relic, it gives me the following table:

| DATE OF EVENTTIME | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| December 9, 2021 | 1.76 M |

However, I want to know what numbers I have after 6 but New Relic doesn't show it. How can I make New Relic show the entire number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the absolute value like so:

`SELECT abs(count(*)) FROM requests WHERE foo = 'bar' FACET dateOf(eventtime) SINCE 3 days ago`

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options suggested by Andy Cunningham in [newrelic discuss](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/not-humanize-count-results/41407)

1. > You can, however, access the [JSON](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/query-your-data/explore-query-data/use-charts/chart-types/) widget type to get the raw values.
2. > multiply the count() function by 1, like so:

> ```
> SELECT count(*)*1 AS 'Total' FROM
> ```

3. > you may want to look at using the [Query API](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/insights-apis/query-insights-event-data-api/) instead. This will allow you to get the query results in JSON format

Comment: I see. The `*1` didn't work for me. It's a pity those are the only options.